# How do I make my siri shorcut run repatedly

Tags: swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have a working sirikit shortcut where user is able to ask a question to my app by saying "Hey siri, ask (appName)". After this, siri asks for the question parameter to the user then the handler function answers the question user asked. However, I want the user to be able to make continuous conversations without having to say "ask ...." each time. I want siri to send me the next question after each question answered. ChatGPT provides such functionality where you can speak to chatGPT through siri continuously. I am not sure how they achieved this. Can someone explain to me how to provide continuous chat with my siri shortcut?

I tried converting my intent to an appIntent thinking it may me possible if I use an appIntent but I could not make the appIntent shortcut work. It says something like an internal error occurred when I try to run my shortcut.